# Store data permanently on iPhone even if the app is deleted

Tags: ios, xamarin, storage

Want to ask if it is possible to store data permanently on iPhone even if the app is deleted.
This means when the app is re-installed, the saved data still can be retrieved.

Comment: You can store it in a public folder, but the user can delete it.  I don't think there is any guaranteed way to store the data without backing it up to a server

Comment: On iOS you cannot do that without special permissions and you shouldn't. What you should do instead is host a cloud infrastructure and save the data there per user. That way, users also have access to the data when they switch devices.

Comment: It depends on how much data you are talking about. Data in the keychain is kept until the device is erased